# Accepting 2 keyboard inputs at once using KeyListener

Tags: java, awt, keylistener

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == 32){ //spacekey
        if (menu.isRun == true){ //Checks if menu is active or not
            if (framecount > 10){ //Prevents too many missiles
                instance.player.spaceKeyPressed();
                framecount = 0;
            }
        }
        menu.isRun = true; //sets menu to inactive
        if (toggle != true){//prevents reopening game after a game over
            if (menu.spaceKeyPressed()){
                instance.CanRun = true; //loads game
                toggle = true;
                menu.update();//updates menu
            }
        }
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == 39) instance.player.rightKeyPressed();//right key moves player right
    if (e.getKeyCode() == 37) instance.player.leftKeyPressed(); //left key moves player left
}
```

With this the user can only move or shoot, not both at once. For example if the user is holding right arrow to move right and presses space the user will stop.

Comment: Write `if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)`, rather than testing for 39.  Your code will be considerably easier to understand.

Comment: @VGR *"Your code will be considerably easier to understand."* I also use the constants for compile time sanity checking. A compiler won't pick up `93` instead of `39`, but it *will* detect there is something wrong with `KeyEvent.VK_RIHGT`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Class-level attribute collection to determine which other keys are pressed. You will have to implement logic for more than one key being pressed in the `keyPressed` function that iterates the list. Also remove the key from the list in the `keyReleased` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean keyA=false;
boolean keyD=false;

//    keys
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key= e.getKeyCode();

    if(key==KeyEvent.VK_A){
        keyA=true;
    }

    if(key==KeyEvent.VK_D){
        keyD=true;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int key= e.getKeyCode();

    if(key==KeyEvent.VK_A){
        keyA=false;
    }

    if(key==KeyEvent.VK_D){
        keyD=false;
    }

//In constructor
new Thread(()->{
    while(true){
        try{Thread.sleep(10);}
        catch (InterruptedException e){}

        if(keyA)
            player.moveLeft();
        if(keyD)
            player.moveRight();
    }
}).start();
```

Notice the usage of `KeyEvent.VK_A`, makes life much simpler.
Also, make sure you have sleep() in your thread, because if it's just while(true) nothing in the loop will execute.